# Is there a way to annotate the INSTANCE field of kotlin objects?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Kotlin object that has several fields exposed as static `@JvmFields`. The parser that I use (which I cannot edit or change) looks for `public static` fields and creates a configuration file based on those. Since the `INSTANCE` field is public too, the parser generates a new category called `instance`. Is there a way to add actual annotations to the `INSTANCE` field? I would want to add the @Ingore annotation to it so the parser does not use the `INSTANCE` field.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the answer is no, Kotlin does not allow annotating or altering the `INSTANCE` fields in any other way. If you believe this could be a useful feature, please file a feature request at [kotl.in/issue](https://kotl.in/issue).

The valid solutions to this problem are:

- Make the bytecode analyzing tool Kotlin-aware, i.e. make it behave correctly with Kotlin declarations. Though this requires non-trivial job to be done and does not seem possible in your case, it could be a valuable time investment.
- Create another ad-hoc tool that post-processes the classes produced by the Kotlin compiler and adds the annotations you need, then include that tool into your build.

Comment: The parser just scans at runtime for all public fields. A post-processing methods sounds the most viable one to be honest. I find it kind of strange that we cannot add annotations to the instance field. Kotlin gives quite a lot of freedom by default.